# How to create a connection between Infopath and Project Server?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence, infopath2010, project-server, ms-project-server-2010

SO Gurus,

I've an Infopath form that should be published to a Sharepoint site as a list/library and I need to be able to update/edit the fields on the Infopath form which updates the Gantt chart in MS Project. I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology here, this is my first time doing this & it would be really helpful if someone can point me in the right direction. Also please correct me if necessary.

My next step in the process is to be able to update/talk to Business Intelligence. I'm not sure how this whole strategy ties together but all I've been told is to make it work!!!(my boss expects a frickin miracle). In short I need to create a comm link between Infopath/Sharepoint/Project Server/Business Intelligence. If there are other methods to approach this, I'd be glad to implement it.

I program in c# and decent skills in sql queries and stored procedures.

Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your first port of call should probably be the [Project Server Interface (PSI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457477.aspx), which exposes Project Server functionality via a web services interface. InfoPath is set up to consume web services relatively easily, you may not even need to break out your C# skills, the JavaScript scripting used by InfoPath will probably allow you to achieve pretty much everything you need.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I'll investigate into this and post the progress. My account is setup to receive emails once/day and I was just notified of your reply but your response was 12hrs ago. must change settings.